# LocationAwareLogger not recognizing parameters

Tags: java, slf4j

Trying to make a wrapper around Logger that logs from the right location

```
default LocationAwareLogger log() {
    return (LocationAwareLogger) LoggerFactory.getLogger( this.getClass() );
}

default void logClick( final String message ) {
    log().trace( this.getClass().getName() );
    log().log( null,
               Loggable.class.getName(),
               LocationAwareLogger.DEBUG_INT,
               "{} click '{}'",
               new Object[] { getContext().getName(), message }, null );
}
```

but when it runs it's not recognizing the parameters

```
20151117 16:48:53,964 DEBUG [main] ClickClose[22]: {} click '{}'
```

what do I have to change to make parameters work?

note: using v1.6.1  and the Log4j adapter

Answer (score 0):

so the answer appears that in at least our version of the log4j adapter, that it does not do message formatting, in fact the first and last 2 arguments are completely ignored by this method. I decided to pass them anyways... but this means that I have to call the formatter directly.

For anyone seeing this in the future it also appears that the 2nd parameter is not the log origin class but where on the stack you want to start ignoring for log purposes, so when logging from within the interface, I want to ignore the class that is the interface, if I chose `this.getClass()` I noticed it was logging from 2 levels above the logging interface..

```
default void logClick( final String message ) {
    FormattingTuple tuple = MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(
        "{} click '{}'", new Object[] { getContext().getName(), message } );
    log().log( null,
               Loggable.class.getName(),
               LocationAwareLogger.DEBUG_INT, tuple.getMessage(),
               tuple.getArgArray(), tuple.getThrowable() ); // last 2 args are ignored pass them anyways
}
```